# What is the meaning of "instantiate" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is the context:

> **Kahneman**: 
>   [To Schiff] It could be that your research could isolate an area in the brain that is associated with
>   consciousness. I’m speculating. And then if we found animals that don’t have that area of the brain, we
>   would have some reason to say they don’t have consciousness. But that would really conflict with the
>   intuitions associated with a robot that certainly doesn’t have those areas of the brain but can generate in
>   us the intuition that it has consciousness. So, I don’t really see a way out of this.
>
> **Schiff**: The problem with the robot as an analogy, I think, is that it typically isn’t the case that most intuitions
>   about consciousness come from observing other people; importantly, they also come from introspective aspect of examining natural language and having—or at least taking the attitude that we have—subjective
>   experience, and then acting accordingly and sharing it, as you would say.
>
> **Kahneman**: But you could surely program a robot to do all of the above . . .
>
> **Schiff**: You could; but if you knew it was a robot, then that might be the reason why you wouldn’t
>   attribute consciousness to it; and that wouldn’t be a bad reason. Unless we have a mechanistic understanding
>   of consciousness and then **instantiate** that mechanism in the robot, we wouldn’t likely attribute
>   consciousness.
>
> source: The enigma of human consciousness.New York Academy of Sciences.

What is the meaning of "instantiate" in this context? I searched the word and find out that the meaning of this word is:

> To represent (an abstract concept) by a concrete or tangible example

But I can't figure out this meaning have anything to do with the sentence in context. So, Can anyone explain the meaning of this word in this context?

Comment: You have an mechanistic understanding of consciousness (you think of consciousness working like a machine) and then you make an actual real machine (a robot) that works like your understanding. The understanding is abstract (an idea) the robot is physical, concrete, tangible.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you very much.